# Developer console Android Vitals

Tags: developer-console

I am looking at my apps errors on the Developer Console site, Android vitals screen.
I am able to see I have several errors there and I would like to debug them.
But those errors don't provide specific information on the line code.
They are something like this:

> java.lang.NullPointerException:    at
>
> app.package.name.MyFragment$6.run(MyFragment.java:0)

I see the class that fails, which is MyFragment but I don't know the line of code. So this is really difficult to fix.

Another example:

> java.lang.NullPointerException:    at
>   app.package.name.MyActivity.MyFunction(MyActivity.java:0)   at
>   app.package.name.MyActivity$14.run(MyActivity.java:0)

In this case I see it is in MyFuction(), inside the class MyActivity, but even so. I would like to know the line.

If I remember well, we were able to see the line numbers before, weren't we?

By the way, I upload the proguard file to deobfuscate:

> ...MyApp\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt